# Prevent output redirection to /dev/null

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have

```
$($(<command>) &>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null
```

Now I want to see the output of the `command` at the shell. Is this possible in any way?

The `command` may sends output to both stdout and stderr but not to a file. I want to get at least one of stdout or stderr.

Comment: You mean it's currently running, and you'd want to see its output without having to stop it and run it again without the redirections to /dev/null?

Comment: And how does the command produce output? Stdout or stderr or both or directly to files?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The command sends output to both stdout and stderr but not to a file. I want to get atleast one of stdout or stderr.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Precisely. Also I can't stop it and read from a file etc.

Comment: You can `strace -p thepid -s 20000 -e write` (or the equivalent command on your system truss/tusc...) or attach a debugger to it, `call close(1)` and reopen some other file for stdout to get to.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null` is an empty pit where 1's and 0's go to die. Your stdout and stderr is lost forever. However in the future out could redirect the output to a file. `command &> /tmp/my_out_file` and then look at the output later with `cat /tmp/my_out_file`

Comment: Yes I know that. But I'm trying to bypass it "somehow". Some "hack" that would give me an output on the shell.

Comment: Unless I am missing something you should just be able to not redirect it to `/dev/null`?

Comment: No, that is the constraint.... I only control the `command` .